# Qt Thread Optimization

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, optimization

I've tryed to profile one of my application using Qt.
The results I found seemed to show that Qt is a big Thread user. It seems to create and destroy threads a lot. Which is the peak of its memory consumption. Is it true ?

So I've tryed to do some research on "how to optimize a Qt application" but, well I hadn't found anything relevant for now.

So I was wondering if there is any "general way" of programming with Qt that could be optimized. Shall I use the threads in a specific manner ? Can I do anything except respecting C++ standards, -pedantic options in compiler, and so one ?

Comment: You will have to start from the general optimization threads in C++. See for example http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Writing_efficient_code/Thread_usage

Comment: How have you profiled it?

Comment: I used Very Sleepy and the VTune Trial. I tryed to watch the process with Process Explorer too. However, I'm not used to these tools ...

Comment: Are you creating threads?

Comment: Somewhere I do. But now specially with or for Qt. It's just that the profiling showed that "KilDispatchInterrupt" has the biggest CPI. Then comes "QtEventDispatcherWin32". So I thought that it was Thread related. I believe that this CPI is Qt-related. But maybe i'm completely wrong. What do you think ?

Comment: Very Sleepy shows the cumulative times. This means if method A is entered at t = 0s, then method A calls method B at t = 1s, method B returns at t = 10s and method A returns at t = 10s, it will show that method A took 10 seconds and method B took 9 seconds. I think there is an option to show only the time actually spent in that method. Generally, Qt usually only has a single thread, which is the Event Loop which processes any kind of event (mouse click, paint request, etc)

Comment: QtEventDispatcherWin32 is event loop "translator" from platform events to Qt events. It will be called a lot even if you have only one thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you create and destroy threads a lot, then that's probably not a very good design. Assuming your threads do the same (or similar) things, then having a fixed "pool" of threads that run for as long as it takes and then get put back in the pool when your current code destroys the thread.

Or, let the thread run forever, and feed it data through some suitable IPC.

I would also say that unless you are doing something very special, if something takes less than about a quarter of a second to do, then you shouldn't create a thread to do that. That's not a fixed rule.

Threads as such don't use that much memory, but the stack of each thread may use quite a bit of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating and destroying QThreads a lot, consider using a [QThreadPool](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qthreadpool.html) or [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html). These will hold threads in reserve and serve them on demand.

If you're not creating and destroying threads a lot, then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You said "my problem". Is a high KillDispatchInterrupt CPI considered as a problem ?

Comment: Not knowing much about your code, it's hard to know whether it is a problem. This link seems to have some information on that process: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/pFJWpeHB3Vs

Comment: From Googling around, I can't tell whether KiDispatchInterrupt is an IO operation or a Mutex operation. Either way it sounds like your CPU is sitting around waiting for something to happen.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a hardware or kernel guy, so I don't know more than that.